# How can I invalidate a SwiftUI View in response to a notification?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm new to SwiftUI and trying to start using it in a complex, existing UIKit app. The app has a theming system, and I'm not sure how to get the SwiftUI view to respond to theme change events.

Our theme objects look like

```swift
class ThemeService {
  static var textColor: UIColor { get }
}

struct ViewTheme: {
  private(set) var textColor = { ThemeService.textColor }
}
```

where the value returned `ThemeService.textColor` changes when the user changes the app's theme. In the UIKit portions of the app, views observe a `"themeChanged"` `Notification` and re-read the value of the `textColor` property from their theme structs.

I'm not sure how to manage this for SwiftUI. Since `ViewTheme` isn't an object, I can't use `@ObservableObject`, but its `textColor` property also doesn't change when the theme changes; just the value returned by calling it changes.

Is there a way to somehow get SwiftUI to re-render the view hierarchy from an external *event*, rather than from a change in a value that the view sees? Or should I be approaching this differently?

Comment: You need an observable property which reflects your current `textColor` value.  You can use Combine to listen for the theme change notification, capture the new value(s) and update your observable properties. SwiftUI will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by cheating with the theming system a little and changing the `ViewTheme` to an object:

```swift
class ViewTheme: ObservableObject {
  private(set) var textColor = { ThemeService.textColor }

  init() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name("themeChanged"), 
                                           object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
      self?.objectWillChange.send()     
    }
  }
}
```

Now the view can mark it with `@ObservedObject` and will be re-generated when the `"themeChanged"` notification is fired.

This seems to be working great, but I'm not sure if there are non-obvious problems that I'm missing with this solution.

Comment: This works fine. I'll add another option in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer works perfectly well, but it requires adoption of ObservableObject. Here is an alternative answer which uses your existing NotificationCenter notifications to update a SwiftUI view.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var textColor: UIColor

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .foregroundColor(Color(textColor))
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name("themeChanged"))) { _ in
                textColor = ThemeService.textColor
            }
    }
}
```

This requires a @State variable to hold the theme's current data, but it's correct because a SwiftUI view is really just a snapshot of what the view should currently display. It ideally should not reference data that is arbitrarily changed because it leads to data-sync problems like the question you asked. So in a SwiftUI view, it is problematic to write `ThemeService.textColor` directly within the body unless you are certain an update will always occur *after* it the theme gets changed.

Comment: Okay, and I think this solution should also propagate changes to subviews, if I put the `.onReceive()` modifier on the top-level content view and deep subviews use the state properties?

Comment: @Greg If the state properties percolate down into subviews, yep! Should work. If you run into frame-skips when changing the color down the line, you can improve that by only doing this "observation" down within the subviews that actually care about color rather than the root view. Basically your entire app needs to refresh for something that only affects 2% of its views. Might be totally fine, but in a complex app it's a no go eventually.